# C# Converting a string value to a byte

Tags: c#, string, byte

I need a bit of help, How would I go about converting the below to a byte.

```
string s = "0x01";
byte b = Convert.toByte(s); //(Tried this) ??
byte c = byte.Parse(s); //(Tried this as well)
```

How would I convert s to a byte ?

Comment: The code isn't even valid. You can't assign `0x01` to a string. Fix it to the actual string you have.

Comment: Sorry I quickly type the top to try an explain the problem.

Comment: Are you only going to convert strings on the format of `0x??` or do you need to support binary, octal, decimal as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the parse function won't allow the prefix 0X in the string so you might use sub-string to remove it.

```
byte myByte = Byte.Parse(s.SubString(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Or use -

```
byte myByte = Convert.ToByte(s,16);
```

Comment: Why convert first to `int`? `ToByte` also accepts radix.

Comment: Just another way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Why add another unnecessary step? `Convert.ToByte("0xef", 16)` works correctly.

Comment: Kiziu is correct: You don't need to strip off the `0x` and you don't need to convert to an `int` first.

Comment: Remove the second suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Techidiot, you shouldn't have removed it, just slightly change it, to `Convert.ToByte(s, 16)`.

Comment: Thanks. Done. Not sure what I thought earlier. May be a code from one of my source.

Comment: Does byte not have TryParse?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove "0x" from the string value and then use parse() method with NumberStyles.HexNumber

```
string s = "AA";
byte byteValue = 0; 
try
{
    byteValue = byte.Parse(s, NumberStyles.HexNumber | NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e);
}

Console.WriteLine("String value: 0x{0}, byte value: {1}", s, byteValue);
```